# Unity NetworkServer OnServerStarted

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I am trying to setup a NetworkServer <-> NetworkClient in Unity
I prefer not to use the NetworkManager because it requires setting Online/Offline scene. I'd like the player to stay in the same scene and handle most of what NetworkManager does myself for learning purposes.

My issue is that I can't find out when the server starts.
Now the NetworkBehaviour class has a virtual void [OnStartServer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkBehaviour.OnStartServer.html) and in the documentation it says NetworkServer.Listen() 'could' trigger it.

Any information about when this function is triggered ?
And what is the difference between Network.InitializeServer() and NetworkServer.Listen() is Network.InitializeServer() the legacy server from Unity ?

Current code :

```
public class MyCustomNetworkManager : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public void StartServer()
    {
        NetworkServer.Listen("127.0.0.1", 1234);
        NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnClientConnect);

        //This in relation with OnServerInitialized Message from Unity works but can't connect with this connection.
        //Network.InitializeServer(4, 1234, false);
    }

    public override void OnStartServer()
    {
        //This does not get called what so ever.
    }

    public void OnClientConnect(NetworkMessage message)
    {
        Debug.Log("A player connected");
    }

    void OnServerInitialized()
    {
        //This works but NetworkClient cannot connect with this server.
    }
}
```